# DD-WRT/openwrt - speed up network sharing function

Tags: router, nas, storage, dd-wrt, openwrt

Can I squeeze more speed out of my router (when it comes to USB attached storage device on it) with open/DD wrt? (Sorry I don't really know such firmwares.)

(Guess it works with ntfs-3g? I don't know.)
**Feel free to make this a real question. Basically the question: Does the change worth it in the terms of speed?**

(My router is a TP-Link WR1043N. Edited it out of the question since it would make it too specified.)

Comment: It would be nice to see NAS in the question title

Comment: It's not a NAS but a mere router with such function. :}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The speed of your USB attached storage device mostly depends on hardware, and on the bandwidth of your USB connection.

There is little difference in speed between OpenWRT and DD-WRT. Both projects allow you to overclock your system, which could speed up processing power a bit.

Comment: I didn't mention this part. HDD supports ~60MB/s, USB supports ~40-50MB/s at full. Router gives ~2MB/s at best. :/

Comment: The router is probably limited by the processor on the board. According to http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database , looks like a TP-Link WR1043N has 32M of RAM and something like a 400Mhz processor. I'm not sure what speeds you could expect, but it is just a router.

Comment: Okay okay... thought I can squeeze out a bit more. :)

Comment: Based on [some benchmarks I've seen on other hardware](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/hardware/performance), the speed mainly depends on the filesystem.  Reformatting the drive as ext4 or hfs+ might help significantly.

Answer (score 0):

These routers are just not designed to work as a speedy NAS. You really are not going to see 60MB/s speeds with a consumer router. The CPU inside them is just far too weak to handle the routing and the various software layers required, not to mention they are completely RAM starved so all read/writes must happen in relatively small blocks.